# How to write php output to file in readable format

Tags: php, json, file-io

I am getting the result from the SOAP client as an response. I tried to get this output and format it in my php code. Now i want to write this output in file in user readable format. I tried Ob_start() method but it was not printing the output and i tried other methods of file writing but its writing with with html code dont know why and its not readable at all. I'm thinking of using JSON to do that, but don't know how to use it.

Code:

```
if($parameter['aktion'] == 'getVehicle') 
{ 
    ob_start();
    var_dump(Login());
    $s = ob_get_clean();
     $vehicle = getVehicleValuation();
     $Serial=$vehicle['SerialEquipment'];   
     $VehicleFuel=$vehicle['VehicleFuel'];
     ob_start();

    Ob_start();
     echo "ECE_In=>". $VehicleFuel->ECE_In . "<br>";
         echo "ECE_Out=>". $VehicleFuel->ECE_Out . "<br>";
         echo "ECE_All=>". $VehicleFuel->ECE_All . "<br>";
         echo "ECE_CO2=>". $VehicleFuel->ECE_CO2 . "<br>";                  



       foreach($Serial as $key => $obj)
       {
            echo "<b>"."Serial Equipment=>" . $key . "</b>"."<br>";
            echo "Code=>". $obj->Code . "<br>";
            echo "Desc Short=>". $obj->Desc_Short . "<br>";
            echo "Desc Long=>". $obj->Desc_Long . "<br>";


            foreach($obj->Esaco as $key2 => $obj2)  
            {  
                if($obj2->EsacoMainGroupCode === null){
            // doesn't contain Esaco
            break;
                }
                else{
                  echo "<b>"."Esaco=>" . $key2 . "</b>"."<br>";                 
                echo "EsacoMainGroupCode=>". $obj2->EsacoMainGroupCode . "<br>";
                echo "EsacoMainGroupDesc=>". $obj2->EsacoMainGroupDesc . "<br>";
                echo "EsacoSubGroupCode=>".  $obj2->EsacoSubGroupCode . "<br>";
                echo "EsacoSubGroupCode=>".  $obj2->EsacoSubGroupDesc . "<br>";
                echo "EsacoSubGroupCode=>".  $obj2->EsacoGroupCode . "<br>";
                echo "EsacoSubGroupCode=>".  $obj2->EsacoGroupDesc . "<br>";  
            }       
            }           
         }  
         file_put_contents('/www/1/html/webservices/AutoDoNotificationService/schwackeNet/result1.txt', ob_get_contents());
         ob_end_flush();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to receive? You probably should save your file with `.html` if HTML is in it instead of `.txt` to get it opened and interpreted in your browser as HTML instead as plain/text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP ouput writing in file in non readable format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934812/php-ouput-writing-in-file-in-non-readable-format)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the last two lines with this:

```
$html_content = ob_get_clean(); // save the content in a variable
$file_data = str_replace('<br>', "\n", $html_content); // replace the html new lines with regular new lines
$file_data = strip_tags($file_data); // Remove all html tags
file_put_contents('/www/1/html/webservices/AutoDoNotificationService/schwackeNet/result1.txt', $file_data); // Save the file
echo $html_content; // Display the html
```

Comment: thanks very much man its priting now only data. But everything is printing without new line and spaces.Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Do you mean that the file has no new lines and intervals?

Comment: there is no new lines and intervals. I tried with PHP_EOL,/n but did not work ...