# PHP ouput writing in file in non readable format

Tags: php, json, file-io

I am getting the result from the SOAP client as an response. I tried to get this output and format it in my PHP code. Now I want to write this output in a file in user readable format. It's writing in a file but without any spaces or new lines. I tried with PHP_EOL and /n method but it did not work.

```
if($parameter['aktion'] == 'getVehicle') 
{ 
    ob_start();
    var_dump(Login());
    $s = ob_get_clean();
     $vehicle = getVehicleValuation();
     $Serial=$vehicle['SerialEquipment'];   
     $VehicleFuel=$vehicle['VehicleFuel'];
     ob_start();

    Ob_start();
     echo "ECE_In=>". $VehicleFuel->ECE_In . "<br>";
         echo "ECE_Out=>". $VehicleFuel->ECE_Out . "<br>";
         echo "ECE_All=>". $VehicleFuel->ECE_All . "<br>";
         echo "ECE_CO2=>". $VehicleFuel->ECE_CO2 . "<br>";                  



       foreach($Serial as $key => $obj)
       {
            echo "<b>"."Serial Equipment=>" . $key . "</b>"."<br>";
            echo "Code=>". $obj->Code . "<br>";
            echo "Desc Short=>". $obj->Desc_Short . "<br>";
            echo "Desc Long=>". $obj->Desc_Long . "<br>";


            foreach($obj->Esaco as $key2 => $obj2)  
            {  
                if($obj2->EsacoMainGroupCode === null){
            // doesn't contain Esaco
            break;
                }
                else{
                  echo "<b>"."Esaco=>" . $key2 . "</b>"."<br>";                 
                echo "EsacoMainGroupCode=>". $obj2->EsacoMainGroupCode . "<br>";
                echo "EsacoMainGroupDesc=>". $obj2->EsacoMainGroupDesc . "<br>";
                echo "EsacoSubGroupCode=>".  $obj2->EsacoSubGroupCode . "<br>";
                echo "EsacoSubGroupCode=>".  $obj2->EsacoSubGroupDesc . "<br>";
                echo "EsacoSubGroupCode=>".  $obj2->EsacoGroupCode . "<br>";
                echo "EsacoSubGroupCode=>".  $obj2->EsacoGroupDesc . "<br>";  
            }       
            }           
         }  
     $content = ob_get_clean(); 
     $file_data = str_replace('<br>', "\n", $content); 
     $file_data = strip_tags($file_data); 
     file_put_contents('/www/1/html/webservices/schwackeNet/result.txt', $file_data); 
     echo $content;
}
```

Comment: text file therefore try \r\n or just \r s the ending.  Failing that don't use file put contents open a file and write it line at a time instead of using php output buffering.

Comment: What's the purpose of echoing `<br>` over and over again if you actually want normal linefeeds?

Comment: its backward slash. \n\r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output a new line, use: \r\n

if you want to output a tab use :\t

also, use a space if you want.

something like:

```
 echo "EsacoMainGroupCode => ". $obj2->EsacoMainGroupCode . "<br>\r\n";
```

if you don't want to output the `<br>`, just remove it from the line.

Best regards,

Comment: thank you its running now and can i bold or do anything to highlights the texts in notepad ?

Comment: i'M confused about your request. A notepad can't make a bold text (notepad++ yes.) or "word" too. If you want to output to a word format, it's a little bit complicated that just output txt plain text from php.